# For survival mode, did they add more beds?

Tags: fallout-4

Since survival mode came out along with patch 1.6, did they add more beds to critical locations or are there areas that are extremely dangerous due to lack of beds?

Note:  In survival mode, you can't save the game unless you sleep in a bed.

Comment: Is this something you've observed or are just asking?  I can't find anything saying they added more beds.

Comment: I owned the game only after 1.6 was released, so I never experienced what it was like at 1.0.  I also do not have an option of using an older version because I own the game on Steam.

Comment: I ask this because in many, many areas, there are random sleeping beds in a cave, abandoned building, a mine, etc, right before critical "boss" fights.  I actually have yet to meet a boss without it being "spoiled" for me due to said bed, so it just looks very suspicious.  If I see a random bed somewhere, it means I need to use it and get ready for a fight.

Comment: You can save by exiting the game in Survival as of 1.6, I believe.

Comment: @Vemonus That save is destroyed when you load, though.

Comment: @DCShannon oh, really? So it's more of a quicksave?

Comment: [Here's](https://www.reddit.com/r/fo4/comments/4dttqx/survival_mode_map_routes_with_the_shortest/) a map of all of the beds in the Commonwealth with the shortest distances between them drawn, for reference. [Here's](http://imgur.com/c3xPGgm) the same map without the lines.

Comment: @Vemonus Yeah, I think it's just so you can stop playing whenever without breaking their rule that you can only save progress at a bed. The progress isn't really saved in the sense that you can go try other stuff and then load your previous point, it just lets you leave the game and come back.

Comment: @DCShannon That makes more sense. I wouldn't know because I haven't attempted a Survival run yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If they have, I certainly haven't noticed.

By the time the new survival mode had come out, I had already made a character with the express intention of exploring every building in the Commonwealth. I didn't have a checklist to work with, but I completed that goal to my satisfaction prior to starting Survival mode.

I have not noticed any new beds anywhere.

That being said, there really are quite a few beds around, and you can always make some in a nearby settlement. As long as you don't mind losing your adrenaline, you can usually find a bed to sleep in fairly near your goal.

To illustrate this, Vemonus has provided [a link to a Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/fo4/comments/4dttqx/survival_mode_map_routes_with_the_shortest/) that shows the locations of all the beds in the Commonwealth. I can't independently verify that this is 100% accurate, but it gives you a pretty good idea of how common they really are.

[image: beds]

Comment: I took an 8-9 month break of Fallout 4 and recently started playing again and I haven't noticed any extra beds laying around where they weren't before, so I'd agree with this.